# What is the purpose of MIN MAX function with dates in Powerbi

Tags: python, powerbi, dax

I am new to Powerbi and I need to plot a graph.
I have customers that were created on a certain date and end on a certain date. Some customers dont have an end date as they are on-going. I want to see count of active patients on each date.I plotted it in Python and then I used DAX in Powerbi. Powerbi isnt giving me correct solution. This is how its done in Python
`import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

```
# Convert date columns to datetime objects
df['ReferralCreatedDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ReferralCreatedDate'])
df['ServiceEndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ServiceEndDate'])

# Generate date range from January 1, 2021, till today
start_date = datetime(2021, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.today()

date_range = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='D')

# Initialize an empty list to store active patient counts for each date
active_patients_by_date = []

# Iterate through each date and calculate active patients
for date in date_range:
    active_patients = df[
        (df['ReferralCreatedDate'] <= date) &
        (  (df['ServiceEndDate'] > date) | (df["ServiceEndDate"].notnull()) )
        ]['RequestNumber'].nunique()

         active_patients_by_date.append(active_patients)

# Create a DataFrame for plotting
plot_data = pd.DataFrame({'Date': date_range, 'Active Patients': active_patients_by_date})

# Plotting
plt.plot(plot_data['Date'], plot_data['Active Patients'], marker='o')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Active Patients')
plt.title('Active Patients Over Time')  
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()`
```

This is the DAX I used:
Active Patients =

`SUMX( FILTER( ALL('SDP_Patients'), 'SDP_Patients'[ReferralCreatedDate] <= SELECTEDVALUE('Total Patients Count'[Date]) && ( 'SDP_Patients'[ServiceEndDate] > SELECTEDVALUE('Total Patients Count'[Date]) ||         ISBLANK(SDP_Patients[ServiceEndDate]) ) ), CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('SDP_Patients'[RequestNumber])) )`

Answer (score 1):

I did this a completely different way. I used PowerQuery to generate all the dates between StartDate and EndDate for each record... Like this:

```
let
Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WcjZU0lEy1DfUNzIwMoYwTSHsWB2grBFYyAIha4QsC9VgDpOGiJqgKNRRMtI3NEHSZIohDTMyFgA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [CustomerID = _t, #"Start Date" = _t, #"End Date" = _t]),
#"Changed text dates to date types" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"CustomerID", type text}, {"Start Date", type date}, {"End Date", type date}}),
#"Replaced Null EndDates to CurrentDate" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed text dates to date types",null,#date(2023, 2, 5),Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"End Date"}),
#"Convert Start and End Dates to NUMBERS" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replaced Null EndDates to CurrentDate",{{"Start Date", Int64.Type}, {"End Date", Int64.Type}}),
#"Created List of numbers from StartDate to EndDate" = Table.AddColumn(#"Convert Start and End Dates to NUMBERS", "ExpandedDate", each {[Start Date]..[End Date]}),
#"Expanded ExpandedDate" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Created List of numbers from StartDate to EndDate", "ExpandedDate"),
#"Converted StartDate and EndDate numbers back to Date datatype" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded ExpandedDate",{{"ExpandedDate", type date}, {"Start Date", type date}, {"End Date", type date}})
```

in
#"Converted StartDate and EndDate numbers back to Date datatype"

The end result is that I have a (PersonID, Date) record in my table for each date the person was active. So counting active people is a snap. COUNTROWS('Table') Then I just graph that on a line graph with the dates on the X-axis.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use slicer in power BI to filter data on date range.
Step1: create the visualization.

Step2: create slicer on the same Page with the date column.
Step3: go to format of the slicer and select 'Between' Style Option on Visual tab.

[image: Screenshot]